# How do I access the JWT Token after authentication for a Cognito AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot

In AWS Cognito, In add a user to a group. I use spring boot and angular.
How can I can get the JWT Token after authentication with Cognito AWS ?
I need to decode the token for getting the group of user.

I want to get this value :

```
{
  "sub": "a18626f5-a011-454a-b4c2-6969b3155c24",
  "cognito:groups": [
    "uw-app-administrator",
    "uw-app-user"
  ],
  "email_verified": true,
  "iss": "https://cognito-idp.<region>.amazonaws.com/<user-pool-id>",
  "cognito:username": "<my-user-name>",
  "given_name": "<my-first-name>",
  "aud": "<audience-code>",
  "token_use": "id",
  "auth_time": 1493918449,
  "nickname": "Bubbles",
  "exp": 1493922049,
  "iat": 1493918449,
  "email": "<my-email>"
}
```

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/jwt/JwtDecoder.html

Comment: Thanks , but I need firts to get the token .. how can I ?

Comment: after you do auth with Cognito, you will get token back